# Python - Creating self-replicating class-object instance

Tags: python, class, automation, replication

I am trying to come up with a way of taking a created instance that acts as an environment for n-many sub-instances within; like having a overall 'network' instance with multiple dynamically-interconnecting objects inside. My current idea is for the network instance to first be instantiated, and then an initial sub-object created inside. The network would have a way to receive an input and send an output, and those inputs pass by the sub-objects and the sub-objects collectively form an output to send.

What I need is for a way that can have a cell, when certain parameters are met, take itself and create a new object that is a copy of itself but with different name and inserting a different stored data; not replacing the original, but expanding the collective in the network instance. So this would allow for a database-like system that could dynamically expand without being told a set range of object names, but be able to self-replicate. If it would be possible, the objects would replicate themselves as their instances and not call their class, but I'm completely open to ideas.

I have been able to test manually creating individual objects and have them interact how I would like, but still unable to get a simplified way of making the objects class self-replicate on its own initiative. So that's what I really need, sorry for the wall of text, and thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any new-style object can get a reference to its class by accessing its `__class__` attribute. From there it can invoke a constructor, manipulate class attributes, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to give the most straight-forward way of accomplishing my goal with allowing flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replicate an object's current state in a way that allows it to be modified independently of the parent object, use `copy.deepcopy` (or maybe, depending on the values in your object, `copy.copy` is enough.) I'd suggest that an object create a copy of itself and call a method of the container object (the network) to store the copy.

```
def replicate(self, ...):
    clone = copy.deepcopy(self)
    # Modify clone if necessary
    network.add(clone)
```